# Load and display Joomla authentication process (Login page) from external PHP scripts

Tags: authentication

Would it be possible to load the Joomla framework, then to display the standard login (with all regular options and custom plugins, including the login reult) in an external PHP program?

I want to build a SAML IDP server and use the standard Joomla authentication plugins, so I don't have to re-implement all Joomla authentication mechanisms.